# Cannot implicitly convert type list to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Boa noite,

Estou com dúvida no seguinte erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'ITCore.FlowCredit.Business.Entities.ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch'

O Código:

```
private void LoadDia()
    {
        ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch pont = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch();

        ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias aDay = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias();

        int? id_TipoDia = txtDay.Text.ToInt32Nullable();
        DateTime? DiaInicio = dtCreationFrom.Text.ToDateTimeNullable();
        DateTime? DiaFim = dtCreationFrom.Text2.ToDateTimeNullable();
        string id_Produto = txtProduto.Text;

        try
        {
            pont = FlowCreditTaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoProviderManager.Provider.GetTodosDiasAmortizacaoCredito(id_TipoDia, id_Produto);
            if (pont != null)
            {
                BindGridProducts(pont);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHelper.ShowError(ex, false);
        }

    }
```

O erro está em:

```
pont =  FlowCreditTaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoProviderManager.Provider.GetTodosDiasAmortizacaoCredito(id_TipoDia, id_Produto);
```

Isto é a função do provider:

```
#region Gets

public override List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> GetTodosDiasAmortizacaoCredito(int? id_TipoDia, String id_Produto)
{
    List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>();

    try
    {
        ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj = ProdutoAmortizacaoDiasUtils.GetTodosProdutoAmortizacaoDias(id_TipoDia, id_Produto).result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CoreLog.LogError(ex);
        throw new CoreException(ex.Message);
    }
    return ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasObj;
}
```

E aqui é o commonProviders:

```
public abstract List<ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas> GetTodosProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas(DateTime? id_DataAtiva, String id_Produtos);

[DataContract, Serializable]
public class ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDiasSearch
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> result { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal NumberRecords { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ReturnValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor a sua questão, não sei se entendi direito.

Comment: Está resolvido! Obrigado

Comment: Veja bem, tente não levar a mal, mas eu não faço ideia de como você está "programando" sem entender algo extremamente básico como isso. Tente estudar a linguagem, fazer exercícios **básicos**, essas coisas. O começo é sempre o melhor ponto de partida. Não adianta tentar começar escrevendo algo grandioso. Eu vejo que isso parece alguma aplicação comercial e eu não faço ideia do que se passa, mas quis te deixar uma dica. (*Eu estava escrevendo uma resposta para explicar pra você o que acontece e retirei este trechinho dela*).

Comment: Eu agradeço a ajuda jbueno! Estou a trabalhar como programador, mas a minha área é Java e meteram-me num projeto na banca em ASP.NET e ainda estou a aprender como funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque ele não consegue converter a lista de ...Dias que tu retorna para o objeto ...DiasSearch.

**Atualizado**

Substitua a linha que está com erro por:

```
 pont.result = FlowCreditTaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoProviderManager.Provider.‌​GetTodosDiasAmortiza‌​caoCredito(id_TipoDi‌​a, id_Produto);
```

Comment: O que me indicaram abocado foi colocar uma list<> para chamar o metodo. mas como posso eu fazer isso? Não entendi. Ou seja eu tenho de converter a lista para um objeto, certo? O problema é que nao chego lá :S

Comment: Pode colocar as propriedades dos objetos?

Comment: Coloquei na dúvida mais uma parte do código!

Comment: Você precisa colocar pont.result = FlowCreditTaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoProviderManager.Provider.GetTodosDiasAmortizacaoCredito(id_TipoDia, id_Produto);

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! É sempre bom aprender com quem sabe :D Mais uma vez obrigado!